# Using PHP $_GET to grab data and define content

Tags: php

I want to use `PHP`'s `$_GET` in a url to grab data to help define content within the page.

Basically, I want the url to be like this-

`/page.php?p=1`

Then, the PHP would automatically `include ../content/1.txt` later in the code, because 1 was after `p=`. If the url was `/page.php?p=2`, then it would `include ../content/2.txt` because that was in the url. I want it to do this automatically, and within the page, so that a basic skeleton can be put together, and the file is included in that skeleton. I want PHP to do this automatically, instead of having to define every single p= and have it get it from that.

Comment: So why don't you? What's the problem you're having? Sounds like an incredibly trivial application of PHP. If you want a useful answer, provide more details about what you've already tried and what behavior you're seeing that you don't want.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with $_GET and can't find anything useful when searching to help me.

Comment: Then I strongly suggest you find a book or other resource on the basics of PHP because this is insanely trivial. `stackoverflow` is a great place to come once you have a general understanding of the language and how to use it but are stuck on specific problems. It's not practical or fair to expect people to teach you how to program here. Also, the PHP site has a lot of documentation and a search bar: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php. That was also the second hit on google when searching for "PHP $_GET".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this...

```
<?php

    if(isset($_GET['p'])){

        $fileName = $_GET['p'];

        /* validate the user input here */

        $fileName = "../content/" . $fileName . ".txt";

        //include the file
        include($fileName);

        //or echo a link to the file
        echo "<a href=\"" . $fileName . "\">Link</a>";

        //or echo the file's contents
        echo file_get_contents($fileName);
    }
?>
```

Comment: It wouldn't be an SQL injection, it would be a filesystem traversal attack. But you're right, you need to validate the parameters to make sure you're not being attacked.

Comment: Good point. The file is on the file system, not in db

Comment: @sh1ftst0rm: only if on incredibly ancient webservers. you can't break out of the document root on a modern webserver without server-side intervention.

Comment: @MarcB: There's plenty of amateur/hobbyist servers out there that aren't `chroot`'d (mine, for instance). Besides, you don't necessarily have to break out of the doc root to pull off an attack, just get somewhere that the site author didn't intend. Regardless of whether you expect to be chrooted or have any other protection, you should always validate any input from the user.

Comment: Just realized the example code is generating a link. I don't think it was like that originally (or what the OP intended), but either way, it should be validated just for the sake of having a quality site (graceful error handling instead of a 404).

Answer (score 3):

`page.php:`

```
if(isset($_GET['p']) && is_numeric($_GET['p'])){
    include('../content/'.$_GET['p'].'.txt');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Should do the trick

```
if($_POST['p'] =='1'){
$content = file_get_contents('/content/1/');
echo $content;
}
```

and so on...

Comment: He doesn't want to write every case and he wants to include the file, not echo it.

Comment: He also wants to get it from `$_GET`, not `$_POST`.